# Calculating difference of dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to calculate difference of two dates in Oracle. It's not a problem, but there is a condition.
I made a timestamp when the task was created and then new timestamp when the task was finished. And I need to calculate the difference, but:

When the task was created and finished in the same day I need to get the difference = 1 (because they were working on it for one day) and when the task was started yesterday and finished today I need the difference = 2.
I hope you understand, if not ask me for more information.

Comment: show us what you have tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume here that your dates are held in columns of type DATE.  If so, the following should do what you want:

```
SELECT TRUNC(END_DATE) - TRUNC(START_DATE) + 1 AS ELAPSED_DAYS
  FROM A_TABLE
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
select date2 - date1 + 1 from <tablename>
```

Comment: you might want to use `trunc()` to get rid of the time part if only complete days should be considerd.

Answer (score 0):

```
select MOD(24 * (to_date('2009-07-08 23:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
         - to_date('2009-07-07 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')), 24)+1 diff_days 
   from dual;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8089/18)